# How to unify schema when writing to parquet in apache spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a schema eg: A which I use to read:

```
val DF = spark.read.schema(A.schema).json(inputPath)
```

Now I have a different schema lets say D which is a union of A + B + C.
When writing to parquet I want to make sure that data frame is written to parquet with schema D. I am trying to think how can I achieve this. Any ideas would be helpful in this regard how can I approach this problem.

Comment: why not a different file, why make things complex?

Comment: @thebluephantom What do you mean by different file ?